# Drawing an arrow with sharp edges in figure area

Tags: matplotlib

I am using matplotlib in python 2.7. I am trying to create an arrow in the figure area outside of the axes.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

fig = figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([.1,.1,.6,.8])

ax1.annotate('',xy=(.8,.92),xycoords='figure fraction',xytext=(.8,.1)
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->',fc='k',lw=10))

ax2 = fig.add_axes([.85,.1,.1,.8])
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.tick_params(axis='both',which='both',
                top='off',right='off',left='off',bottom='off',
                labeltop='off',labelright='off',labelleft='off',labelbottom='off')

ax2.patch.set_facecolor('None')

ax2.set_xlim(0,1)
ax2.set_ylim(0,1)
ax2.arrow(.5,0,0,1,fc='k',ec='k',head_width=.25,
          head_length=.05,width=.15,length_includes_head=True)    
show()
```

Using

```
ax1.annotate(...)
```

gives me a 'blurry' looking arrow. The only way I can figure out how get a better looking arrow is by creating another axes just for adding the arrow and using

```
ax2.arrow(...)
```

(the website won't let me post an image, but copy and paste the code and you'll see what I'm talking about)
There's got to be a better way to do this though...

Answer (score 1):

I think changing the arrowstyle will help here. For example, changing it to `'simple'` from `'->'` gives a better looking arrow. You can change the width by playing with the `mutation_scale`. For example,

```
ax1.annotate('',xy=(.8,.92),xycoords='figure fraction',xytext=(.8,.1),
    arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="simple",fc="k", ec="k",mutation_scale=30))
```

Here's your script, with the above `simple` arrow plotted in blue. Note the difference to the black arrow plotted as a `->` arrow with `annotate`.

```
from matplotlib.pyplot import *

fig = figure()
ax1 = fig.add_axes([.1,.1,.5,.8])

# Your original arrow (black)
ax1.annotate('',xy=(.7,.92),xycoords='figure fraction',xytext=(.7,.1),
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle='->',fc='k',lw=10))

# "Simple" arrow (blue)
ax1.annotate('',xy=(.8,.92),xycoords='figure fraction',xytext=(.8,.1),
             arrowprops=dict(arrowstyle="simple",fc="b", ec="k",mutation_scale=30))

ax2 = fig.add_axes([.85,.1,.1,.8])
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['left'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax2.tick_params(axis='both',which='both',
                top='off',right='off',left='off',bottom='off',
                labeltop='off',labelright='off',labelleft='off',labelbottom='off')

ax2.patch.set_facecolor('None')

ax2.set_xlim(0,1)
ax2.set_ylim(0,1)
ax2.arrow(.5,0,0,1,fc='r',ec='k',head_width=.25,
          head_length=.05,width=.15,length_includes_head=True)    
show()
```

[image]